# Should I use fixed effects or first difference?

Tags: regression, econometrics, fixed-effects-model, economics

I have a panel data which N = 189 and T=3. My dependent variable is growth rate of GDP per capita. I wanted to know which model should I use in this case? Should I use fixed effects or first difference (FD)? Most of my Independent variables are binary variables.

Comment: This can actually be tricky.  See the literature on [Lord's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_paradox) ...

Comment: Usually, FE is preferred with iid errors since it will be more efficient.  FD makes a weaker exogeneity assumption, which usually comes in handy if you have lags of the outcome in your model (dynamics). But in the end, why not do it both ways for robustness?